# executing two different methods with same api address

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2

I have a retrofit class with my own base url,in api service interface one of my methods works but second no,it seems that i 'm not allowed to use two GET response with same address but i need this subject. 
i have executed first method (getTextChar) and worked correctly

Api service interface

public interface ApiService {

```
@GET("1e3b4e")
Single<Word> getTextChar();

@GET("1e3b4e")
Single<Word> getTenMultiple();
```

}

CloudDataSource class

public class EnglishCloudyDataSource extends RetrofitBase {

```
private ApiService apiService;


public EnglishCloudyDataSource() {
    super();
    apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
}


@Override
public Single<Word> getCharText() {
    return apiService.getTextChar();
}

@Override
public Single<Word> getMultipleTen() {
    return apiService.getTenMultiple();
}
```

NewsRepository class

public class NewsRepository implements NewsDataSource {

```
private RetrofitBase retrofitBase;

public NewsRepository() {
    retrofitBase=new EnglishCloudyDataSource();
}


@Override
public Single<Word> getCharText() {
    return retrofitBase.getCharText();
}

@Override
public Single<Word> getMultipleTen() {
    return retrofitBase.getMultipleTen();
}
```

}

Retrofit class

public abstract class RetrofitBase implements NewsDataSource {

```
protected Retrofit retrofit;

public RetrofitBase() {

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

}
```

}

Comment: your params and path both are same, why not use the method created earlier if its going to return same data?

Comment: i 'm aware of something which you said,but need second too

Comment: just curious, why would you go through trouble of creating extra method doing same work and remember it twice?

Comment: If you want the second just for clarification purposes, meaning that you want to make the code more readable, you can create two methods with different signatures but they use the same Retrofit API. Other than that I don't think there is any need to have two methods in the API for the same endpoint.

Comment: @eyadMhanna hi,how can i have different signatures???